# Extract domain names from a file in Shell

Tags: regex, bash, shell, grep, extract

I have a file and it's content is a list of some URLs,
I want to extract the domain names from this list of URLs in bash
Example:

```
sub1.domain.com
domain3.com
sub5.domain.ext
subof.subdomain.domainx.ex2
```

I want to extract just domain names from this list
How can I do this?
Thank you

Comment: Non-regex solution: `(rev|cut -d'.' -f-2|rev) < file.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `grep`:

```
grep -Eo '[^.]+\.[^.]+$' file.txt
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat file.txt
sub1.domain.com
sub2.domains2.com
domain3.com
sub5.domain.ext
subof.subdomain.domainx.ex2

$ grep -Eo '[^.]+\.[^.]+$' file.txt
domain.com
domains2.com
domain3.com
domain.ext
domainx.ex2
```

Note that this will return `co.uk` for `www.google.co.uk`.

Answer (score 4):

A possible solution using Perl:

```
use Domain::PublicSuffix qw( );

my $dps = Domain::PublicSuffix->new();

for my $host (qw(
   www.google.com
   foo.bar.google.com
   www.google.co.uk
   foo.bar.google.co.uk
)) {
   my $root = $dps->get_root_domain($host)
      or die $dps->error();

   say $root;
}
```

Output:

```
google.com
google.com
google.co.uk
google.co.uk
```

Comment: Hi,What is this language?

Comment: Perl. You did tag the question with the perl language tag

Comment: ok, thank you very much