# Python Regex to Extract Domain from Text

Tags: python, regex

I have the following regex:

```
r'(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-]{,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}'
```

When I apply this to a text string with, let's say, 
"this is www.website1.com and this is website2.com", I get:

```
['www.website1.com']

['website.com']
```

How can i modify the regex to exclude the `'www`', so that I get `'website1.com'` and `'website2.com`? I'm missing something pretty basic ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract all domains from text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21211572/extract-all-domains-from-text)

Answer (score 4):

Try this one (thanks @SunDeep for the update):

```
\s(?:www.)?(\w+.com)
```

**Explanation**

`\s` matches any whitespace character

`(?:www.)?` non-capturing group, matches `www.` 0 or more times

`(\w+.com)` matches any word character one or more times, followed by `.com`

And in action:

```
import re

s = 'this is www.website1.com and this is website2.com'

matches = re.findall(r'\s(?:www.)?(\w+.com)', s)
print(matches)
```

Output:

```
['website1.com', 'website2.com']
```

A couple notes about this.  First of all, matching all valid domain names is very difficult to do, so while I chose to use `\w+` to capture for this example, I could have chosen something like: `[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}`.

This answer has a lot of helpful info about matching domains:
[What is a regular expression which will match a valid domain name without a subdomain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306690/what-is-a-regular-expression-which-will-match-a-valid-domain-name-without-a-subd)

Next, I only look for `.com` domains, you could adjust my regular expression to something like:

```
\s(?:www.)?(\w+.(com|org|net))
```

To match whichever types of domains you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here a try :

```
import re
s = "www.website1.com"
k = re.findall ( '(www.)?(.*?)$', s, re.DOTALL)[0][1]
print(k)
```

O/P like :

```
'website1.com'
```

if it is `s = "website1.com"` also it will o/p like :

```
'website1.com'
```