# Create pairs from RDD by using nth element in the row

Tags: python, apache-spark, bigdata, rdd, databricks

I have used this code:

```
def process_row(row):
words = row.replace('"', '').split(' ')
for i in range(len(words)):
      #if we find ‘-’ we will replace it with ‘0’
      if(words[-1]=='-'):
          words[i]='0'
return words
return [words(0),words(1), words(2), words(3), words(4), int(words(5))]

nasa = (
nasa_raw.flatMap(process_row)
)
nasa.persist()
for row in nasa.take(10):
print(row)
```

to transform this data:

```
in24.inetnebr.com [01/Aug/1995:00:00:01] "GET /shuttle/missions/sts-68/news/sts-68-mcc-05.txt" 200 
1839
 uplherc.upl.com [01/Aug/1995:00:00:07] "GET /" 304 0
uplherc.upl.com [01/Aug/1995:00:00:08] "GET /images/ksclogo-medium.gif" 304 0
uplherc.upl.com [01/Aug/1995:00:00:08] "GET /images/MOSAIC-logosmall.gif" 304 0
 uplherc.upl.com [01/Aug/1995:00:00:08] "GET /images/USA-logosmall.gif" 304 0
ix-esc-ca2-07.ix.netcom.com [01/Aug/1995:00:00:09] "GET /images/launch-logo.gif" 200 1713
uplherc.upl.com [01/Aug/1995:00:00:10] "GET /images/WORLD-logosmall.gif" 304 0
slppp6.intermind.net [01/Aug/1995:00:00:10] "GET /history/skylab/skylab.html" 200 1687
piweba4y.prodigy.com [01/Aug/1995:00:00:10] "GET /images/launchmedium.gif" 200 11853
slppp6.intermind.net [01/Aug/1995:00:00:11] "GET /history/skylab/skylab-small.gif" 200 9202
```

into this pipelined rdd:

```
in24.inetnebr.com
[01/Aug/1995:00:00:01]
 GET
 /shuttle/missions/sts-68/news/sts-68-mcc-05.txt
 200
 1839
 uplherc.upl.com
 [01/Aug/1995:00:00:07]
 GET
 /
```

I want to create frequencies of adresses like : **uplherc.upl.com** by using pairs:

```
pairs = nasa.map(lambda x: (x , 1))
count_by_resource = pairs.reduceByKey(lambda x, y : x + y)
count_by_resource =  count_by_resource.takeOrdered(10, key = lambda x: -x[1])
spark.createDataFrame(count_by_resource, ['Resource_location','Count']).show(10)
```

but the result is something of every element frequency:

```
   --------------------+-------+
   |   Resource_location|  Count|
   +--------------------+-------+
   |                 GET|1551681|
   |                 200|1398910|
   |                   0| 225418|
```

How should I refer to my element of interest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splitting each line by spaces and then creating a flatmap of all these values when you are primarily interested in a count of the domains may be giving additional work and definitely additional overhead and processing.

Based on the sample data provided, the domain is the first item on each line. I have also noted that some of your lines begin with an empty space and as such results in an additional string piece. You may considering using the `strip` function to trim the line before the process.

You may consider modifying process to return only the first bit of the string or creating another `map` operation which does.

```py
def extract_domain_from_row(row):
    # if row is a string
    domain = row.strip().split(' ')[0]
    # if you send a list, you could always extract the first item from that list as the domain name
    # domain = row[0]
    return domain.lower()

#intermediary rdd 
nasa_domains = nasa_raw.map(extract_domain_from_row)

# continue operations as desired with `nasa`
pairs = nasa_domains.map(lambda x: (x , 1))
count_by_resource = pairs.reduceByKey(lambda x, y : x + y)
count_by_resource =  count_by_resource.takeOrdered(10, key = lambda x: -x[1])
spark.createDataFrame(count_by_resource, ['Resource_location','Count']).show(10)
```

***Outputs***

```
+--------------------+-----+
|   Resource_location|Count|
+--------------------+-----+
|     uplherc.upl.com|    5|
|slppp6.intermind.net|    2|
|   in24.inetnebr.com|    1|
|ix-esc-ca2-07.ix....|    1|
|piweba4y.prodigy.com|    1|
+--------------------+-----+
```

If the first item is not a domain, you may want to filter your collection using a pattern to match domains see suggestions here [`domain regex suggestions`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49166524/python-regex-to-extract-domain-from-text)